# how to write SQL query to find account numbers from the same SSN

Tags: t-sql

```
 AccountNo  SSN 
 10002000   111-11-1111
 20003000   111-11-1111
 30004000   222-22-2222
```

I want this result set

```
10002000    111-11-1111
20003000    111-11-1111
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for a code.

Answer (score 0):

Its always good to see new people trying their hand in SQL so I will give you a nudge. Please read up on usage and examples [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp)

```
SELECT column_name,column_name
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name operator value;
```